# how to POST radio button values through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this example code:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result1)) {                  
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="vote" value='.$row->avalue.'/>&nbsp;';
                    echo '<label >'.$row->atitle.'</label><br>';
                }
```

this displays 4 radio buttons alongwith their labels.
now I am using the following jquery function to POST.

```
$("#submit_js").click(function() {
    $.post(
    "user_submit.php", 
    {//how to POST data?}, 
    function(data){
    });
});
```

I want to post the value associated with the radio button. but how do i select the value?
how do i determine what radio button is selected and POST it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$("[name='vote']:checked").val()` will get you the value of the selected radio button.

```
$("#submit_js").click(function() {
  $.post(
  "user_submit.php", 
  {vote: $("[name='vote']:checked").val()}, 
  function(data){
  });
});
```

Comment: oops, should be :checked not :selected. I fixed the sample.  It will  be undefined if no radio button is selected.

Answer (score 3):

Jquery serialize is the best way to do this kind of things:
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize

```
$("#submit_js").click(function() {
    $.post(
    "user_submit.php", 
    $("form").serialize(), 
    function(data){
    });
});
```

Comment: That's if you want ALL the input elements from the form

Answer (score 3):

If there is no radio button selected the radio button will not be added to the serialized string. In this case we can make a workaround by adding another one exactly like the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="" checked style="display:none;">
```