# Radio button jQuery toggle issue

Tags: jquery, togglebutton

Trying to get radiobuttons to toggle, post the form which executes the appropriate PHP code, and change the active class. No matter what I tried I can't get it to work. Here's the HTML:

```
<form id="activeform" action="inc/togglevalid.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $events["id"];?>" />
<span class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-xs btn-default <? if ($events['valid']=='yes') echo "active";?>"><input class="radiobtn" type="radio" name="valid" id="yes" value="yes"><?=ucwords($phrase['yes']);?></label>
<label class="btn btn-xs btn-default <? if ($events['valid']=='no') echo "active";?>"><input class="radiobtn" type="radio" name="valid" id="no" value="no"><?=ucwords($phrase['no']);?></label>
</span>
</form>
```

And here is the jQuery code sofar after trying all kinds of variations:

```
$('#activeform .btn').on('click',(function()) {
$.post($(this).parents('form').attr('action'),formInput, function(data){
$(this).sibling.removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
return false;
});
```

It just won't work and another script stops working once I add this code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

warm greetings
John

Comment: if susequent scripts fail There must be an error are you seeing anything in your console?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097816/how-to-post-radio-button-values-through-jquery

Answer (score 0):

you have some extra parathenesis

this line `$('#activeform .btn').on('click',(function()) {`1 should be changed to

`$('#activeform .btn').on('click',function() {`

also "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: formInput is not defined",

```js
$('#activeform .btn').on('click', function() {
  //move these 2 lines to your success function
  $('#activeform btn').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  ////////////////////////////
  var form = $(this).parents('form')
  var formInput = form.serialize();
  $.post(form.attr('action'), formInput, function(data) {
    //add the lines here

  });
  //return false;
})
```

```css
.active {
  /*color: blue;*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form id="activeform" action="inc/togglevalid.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
    <span class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
        <input class="radiobtn" type="radio" name="valid" id="yes" value="yes">yes</label>
      <label class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
        <input class="radiobtn" type="radio" name="valid" id="no" value="no">no</label>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That took care of the error! I can't believe I didn't see that -:). Thanks. But, alas the form is not submitting yet.

Comment: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: formInput is not defined",  double check that console log after you click the radio

Comment: another thing check that click function (you are returning false) so the radio will not "check" is that what you want?

Comment: I now have this. I removed the serialize during all the messing around.

    $('#activeform .btn').on('click',function() {
    var formInput = $(this).parents('form').serialize();
    $.post($(this).parents('form').attr('action'),formInput, function(data){
    $(this).sibling.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    return false;
    });

The only thing not working yet is the active class change. Ideas?

Comment: when are you wanting that change to happen. before post ? or after? what exactly do you want to happen when a user clicks on a radio btn?

Comment: after the post, the db is updated and now the Yes label should become active class, I might even addclass disabled (Bootstrap).

Comment: I had to catch my ride and am away from my  computer. I will take a look later. To help if you haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: I tried to edit my post from mobile and messed it up. I will take a look at it later.