# Multiple radio button list, get selected values in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, radiobuttonlist

I am working on a dynamic multiple choice form builder. In this scenario, the form can have multiple radio button list with a different question and options.

```html
<strong>Question 1 </strong>
<br/>

<input type="radio" value=""><lable>Option1</lable>
<input type="radio" value=""><lable>Option2</lable>
<input type="radio" value=""><lable>Option3</lable>
<input type="radio" value=""><lable>Option4</lable>

<br />


<strong>Question 2 </strong>
<br />
<input type="radio" value=""><lable>Option5</lable>
<input type="radio" value=""><lable>Option6</lable>
```

I make model for this:

```
 public class clsMain
    {
        public string[] selectedAnswer { get; set; }

        public List<ClsQuestions> lstQuestion { get; set; }
        public List<ClsOptions> lstOptions { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClsQuestions
    {
        public string question { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClsOptions
    {
        public int optionid { get; set; }
        public string optionvalue { get; set; }
        public string optionlable { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FromSelectedValues(clsMain model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
          Question @i   
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer[i], "Answer1"+i) 
          <label>Answer1 @i</label>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer[i], "Answer2"+i) 
          <label>Answer2 @i</label>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer[i], "Answer3"+i) 
          <label>Answer3 @i</label>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer[i], "Answer4"+i)
          <label> Answer4 @i</label>    
}
```

In short, I want to get selected options in the controller.

Comment: Do you want the value of radio button in the Post Method?

Comment: Yes selected values

Comment: Have you debugged and check what is inside `SelectedAnswer` array? after post?

Comment: It is working fine when i select all questions, but when i left the first one than it post the null

Comment: and pls provide code in the question instead of images that will be easy to reproduce the problem or see the actual working

Comment: Your models are wrong - you need a (say) `class QuestionVM` with properties `List<ClsOptions> PossibleAnswers` and `[Required]string Selected Answer`, and you pass a list of that view model to the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke dear can you describe it more, please

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221948/how-to-pass-listmodel-to-controller-in-mvc-4/34222792#34222792) for and example of how your view models would be structured

Answer (score 0):

In your html file you need to group radio inputs with a specified name.

First of all, you have to change your question and answer model to make a relation.

```
    public class ClsQuestions
    {
        // Parent ID to be referenced by children
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string question { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClsOptions
    {
        // Parent question id of the option
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public int optionid { get; set; }
        public string optionvalue { get; set; }
        public string optionlable { get; set; }
    }
```

You would change your view like this

```
// A loop on all of the questions
@foreach(var item in lstQuestion) {

  // Get list of all options that related to parent question
  var options = lstOptions.Where(x => x.QuestionID == item.ID).ToList();

  <strong>@(item.question)</strong>
  <br/>

  // Al loop on all found options of current question
  @foreach(var option in options) {

    // Group options by using the name property ('Question'+QuestionID)
    <input type="radio" value="@(option.optionid)" name="Question@(item.ID)"><lable>@(option.optionlable)</lable>
  }
  <br />
}
```

Now, when you're submitting your form, you can send an array of selected options.
[Here is a post for sending selected options to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097816/how-to-post-radio-button-values-through-jquery)